# How to group Parent fields in Twig?

Tags: for-loop, group-by, twig, drupal-8

I have the below data structure:

```
Highlevel group HLG - 1: (field_hlg_level1_title)
Abstract: field_hlg_level1_Abstract
    
    HLG subgroup - 1a: (field_hlg_level2_title)
    Abstract: field_hlg_level2_abstract
    
Highlevel group HLG - 1: (field_hlg_level1_title)
Abstract: field_hlg_level1_Abstract
    
    HLG subgroup - 1b: (field_hlg_level2_title)
    Abstract: field_hlg_level2_abstract

Highlevel group HLG - 2: (field_hlg_level1_title)
Abstract: field_hlg_level1_Abstract
    
    HLG subgroup - 2a: (field_hlg_level2_title)
    Abstract: field_hlg_level2_abstract
    
Highlevel group HLG - 2: (field_hlg_level1_title)
Abstract: field_hlg_level1_Abstract
    
    HLG subgroup - 2b: (field_hlg_level2_title)
    Abstract: field_hlg_level2_abstract
```

My view returns the above data, in the twig template I want to group the parent fields and child fields as below:

```
Highlevel group HLG - 1: 
Abstract: 
    
    HLG subgroup - 1a: 
    Abstract: 
    
    HLG subgroup - 1b:
    Abstract:  
    
Highlevel group HLG - 2:
Abstract: 
    
    HLG subgroup - 2a:
    Abstract:  
    
    HLG subgroup - 2b:
    Abstract:
```

I'm a newbie to twig and not sure where to start. I have the basic twig template ready but juggling with looping.

```
{% for row in rows %}
   <div class="group_hlglevel1">
       {{ field_hlg_level1_title }}
   </div>
{% endfor %}
```

I need help with looping through the parent and child fields and group them accordingly.

---

UPDATE: I'm adding sample data for as-is and expected output:

as-is:

```
field_hlg_level1_title : Highlevel group HLG - 1: 
field_hlg_level1_Abstract : Abstract for Level1
    
field_hlg_level2_title : HLG subgroup - 1a: 
field_hlg_level2_Abstract: sample Abstract for 1a

field_hlg_level1_title : Highlevel group HLG - 1: 
field_hlg_level1_Abstract : Abstract for Level1

field_hlg_level2_title : HLG subgroup - 1b:
field_hlg_level2_Abstract: sample Abstract for 1b
```

My expected output:

```
  field_hlg_level1_title : Highlevel group HLG - 1: 
  field_hlg_level1_Abstract : Abstract for Level1
        
  field_hlg_level2_title : HLG subgroup - 1a: 
  field_hlg_level2_Abstract: sample Abstract for 1a
        
  field_hlg_level2_title : HLG subgroup - 1b:
  field_hlg_level2_Abstract: sample Abstract for 1b
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to add values of same names in a row in an HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69464167/how-to-add-values-of-same-names-in-a-row-in-an-html-table)

Comment: @DarkBee No this question does not match with what i ask for. it groups the rows and not the parent fields. So this is not a duplicate.

Comment: Tomayto, tomahto. Check the first part of the answer I've provided. That will be how you need to merge the array in order to group your items. Anyway, as I've added there, you should do these thing in your controller

Comment: can I do the entire thing in twig template itself? Also how do I find the replacements for display_name and voting? Not sure what those fields are in my environment.

Comment: Can you like dump your data out, so i can see what you working with. Bit confused on how its displayed atm

Comment: ok sure, I'll dump data with some screenshots

Comment: @DarkBee I have added some sample data. can you pls help?

Comment: Please do a `{{ dump(var) }}` in the template...