# TWIG sorting data common key

Tags: arrays, for-loop, multidimensional-array, twig

I've started on twig recently and now i'm faced with the issue that I want to group an array based on multiple common key.

My current array is this: (JSON style)

```
{
"attribute_groups": [

{
    "attribute_group_id": "1",
    "name": "Atribute Group #1",
    "attribute": [
        {
            "attribute_id": "101",
            "name": "Attrib1",
            "value": "Val1",
            "subgroup": "SubGroup A"
        },
        {
            "attribute_id": "102",
            "name": "Attrib2",
            "value": "Val2",
            "subgroup": "SubGroup B"
        },
        {
            "attribute_id": "103",
            "name": "Attrib3",
            "value": "Val3",
            "subgroup": "SubGroup A"
        },
        {
            "attribute_id": "104",
            "name": "Attrib4",
            "value": "Val4",
            "subgroup": "SubGroup B"
        }
    ]
},

{
    "attribute_group_id": "2",
    "name": "Atribute Group #2",
    "attribute": [
        {
            "attribute_id": "201",
            "name": "Attrib5",
            "value": "Val5",
            "subgroup": "SubGroup A"
        },
        {
            "attribute_id": "202",
            "name": "Attrib6",
            "value": "Val6",
            "subgroup": "SubGroup C"
        },
        {
            "attribute_id": "203",
            "name": "Attrib7",
            "value": "Val7",
            "subgroup": "SubGroup A"
        },
        {
            "attribute_id": "204",
            "name": "Attrib8",
            "value": "Val8",
            "subgroup": "SubGroup C"
        }
    ]
}
]
}
```

With basic twig for loop i can

```
{% for attribute_group in attribute_groups %}
This is group: {{ attribute_group.name }}

{% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}
Attribute {{ attribute.name }} has value: {{ attribute.value }}
{% endfor %}

{% endfor %}
```

And output would show attributes grouped by main group:

```
This is group: Atribute Group #1

Attribute Attrib1 has value: Val1
Attribute Attrib2 has value: Val2
Attribute Attrib3 has value: Val3
Attribute Attrib4 has value: Val4

This is group: Atribute Group #2

Attribute Attrib5 has value: Val5
Attribute Attrib6 has value: Val6
Attribute Attrib7 has value: Val7
Attribute Attrib8 has value: Val8
```

As TWIGfiddled: https://twigfiddle.com/cow2ax

Now i would like to have an additional subgrouping by "subgroup" key like:

```
This is group: Atribute Group #1

  SubGroup A has attribues:
          Attribute Attrib1 has value: Val1
          Attribute Attrib3 has value: Val3
  SubGroup B has attribues:
          Attribute Attrib2 has value: Val2
          Attribute Attrib4 has value: Val4

This is group: Atribute Group #2

  SubGroup A has attribues:
          Attribute Attrib5 has value: Val5
          Attribute Attrib7 has value: Val7
  SubGroup C has attribues:
          Attribute Attrib6 has value: Val6
          Attribute Attrib8 has value: Val8
```

How to achieve such subsorting/subgrouping ?

I've found [How to add values of same names in a row in an HTML Table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69464167/how-to-add-values-of-same-names-in-a-row-in-an-html-table) but i cannot wrap my brain around it :|

Comment: Any reason you actually want to do this inside your template? Did you read the sidenote in the linked answer?

Comment: I'd like to keep the core cms controllers unmodified, that's why my template approach seems more reasonable... i can imagine that looping multiple times in the data, just to make a subgrouping possible, will result in higher memory usage and a bit more latecy but what can be done in the situation described above - twig related

Comment: ... I mean, I wouldn't call it a logical decision. Are you familiar with twig extensions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Disclaimer**

As said and already mentioned in the linked answer(s), these are things that shouldn't be done in `twig` itself. It's better to move this logic to the controller or at least use a twig extension in which you then can group everything you want more easily.

More information about why you shouldn't do this inside a template can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72401743/reorganize-array-in-twig)

---

Here is the reworked snippet for your grouping. I've already gave my two cents in the linked questions on how this works, so please read those questions/answers as well if you want more details on how this snippet "works"

```
{% set subgroups = {} %}

{% for attribute_group in attribute_groups %}
    {% set subgroups = subgroups|merge({ ('_'~attribute_group.attribute_group_id): {},}) %}
    
    {% for attribute in attribute_group.attribute %}
        {% if not subgroups['_'~attribute_group.attribute_group_id][attribute.subgroup] is defined %}
            {% set subgroups = subgroups|merge({
                ('_'~attribute_group.attribute_group_id): subgroups['_'~attribute_group.attribute_group_id]|merge({(attribute.subgroup):{},}),
            }) %}                
        {% endif %}
        
        {% set subgroups = subgroups|merge({
            ('_'~attribute_group.attribute_group_id): subgroups['_'~attribute_group.attribute_group_id]|merge({(attribute.subgroup): subgroups['_'~attribute_group.attribute_group_id][attribute.subgroup]|merge([ attribute, ]),}),
        }) %}         
    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}


{% for attribute_group in attribute_groups %}
    {{ attribute_group.name }}
    
    {% for key, attributes in subgroups['_'~attribute_group.attribute_group_id] %}
        {{ key }}
        =============        
        {% for attribute in attributes %}
            {{ attribute.value }}
        {% endfor %}
        =============

    {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

[demo](https://twigfiddle.com/cow2ax/2)