# Twig merge 2 arrays based on value/id

Tags: arrays, twig

I'm creating 2 arrays with objects in a Twig template. **I know it's best to handle this not in the templates but there is no other way to do it (SaaS platform)**.

I have 2 loops:

```
{% set opt_arr = {} %}
{% set var_arr = {} %}

 {% for opt in options %}
   {% set opt_arr = opt_arr | merge([{'title': opt.title, 'id':opt.id}]) %}
 {% endfor %}


 {% for var in vars%}
   {% set var _arr = var _arr | merge([{'title': var.title, 'price':var.price}]) %}
 {% endfor %}

/* result equals something like this => 

[ 
 {"title":"used","id":123},
 {"title":"good","id":213},
 {"title":"new","id":321}
] 
[ 
 {"title":"used","price":199},
 {"title":"good","price":299},
 {"title":"new","price":399}
]
```

I want to join them to a single array like so:

```
{"title":"used","id":123,"price":199},
{"title":"good","id":123,"price":299},
{"title":"new","id":123,"price":399}
```

I tried several things but either it won't join on `title` or it removes some data.

```
{% set all_data = [] %}
{% set all_data = all_data | merge(opt_arr) | merge(var_arr) %}
```

Or

```
{% set opt_arr = opt_arr | merge(var_arr ) %}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You **can't** merge arrays with numeric indices - [merge issue](https://github.com/twigphp/Twig/issues/789)

Comment: `There is no other way to do it` - So you can't register a custom twig extension then?

Comment: @DarkBee: I was affraid of this :( No there's no other way then doing it in the frontend. Is there perhaps a different approach to accomplish this? Perhaps something like `(good):{"id":123,"price":299}`. So merge the arrays on the special key? Your an expert in Twig so you must know somekind of way perhaps? :) Anyway thx for your answer

Comment: One "hack" to solve it, is to prepend the numeric value with a identifier/string as I've done in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75104033/twig-sorting-data-common-key/75107583#75107583)

Comment: That's an interesting approach :) Thx...

Comment: @DarkBee: Sorry I have to ask but I can't get it to work with your answer. Is it possible to make an example? I just don't understand how that answer works with `attribute_groups` and `attribute_group_id ` and how I should use that for my question

Comment: How it is joined? is it based on array index? in your expected array the id is all 123, is it correct?

Comment: Can you post the starting array

Comment: @DarkBee: Ok nevermind I have fixed it differently.... Thanks again for your help!